# How do I separate/visualize polylines that overlap? (Show them next to each other)

Tags: qgis, line, network, flow-map

[image]I have a network of polylines between multiple nodes. All nodes are connected with lines in a two-way system (A->B and B->A). I want to show all the lines at the same time, but the problem is that they overlap and only one correlation are shown (A->B but not B->A). This means that the correlation just seems to be one-way instead of two-way.

How do I show them next to each other using QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @RoKro! Does your line layer have an attribute to identify whether it goes from `A -> B` and vice-versa? If so, you could create a style (I prefer rule-based but categorised and graduated could also work) and add two style items to display both lines. Here you can add various options, including setting an **offset** for both your lines (i.e. give one style item a positive offset, the other a negative offset).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Im not sure if your solution works in this case. The identifiers I have is the coordinates between the nodes (A= CoordX-CoordY -> B= CoordX-CoordY) and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a new text field called 'direction' and then use calculate field with a case statement to work out if the line goes north or south. eg.

CASE WHERE coord_y2 > coord_y1
   THEN "northerly" 
   ELSE "southerly" 
   END

You can then use a rule based style to offset the northerly and/or southerly lines